# how to plot a groupby function using plotly and python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart

I have a dataframe that includes 3 columns
I tried to use the plotly.graph_objs package but it did not display the correct result.

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

    df=pd.DataFrame ({
        "source_number":[11199, 11329, 11298, 33212, 12343],
        "location": ['loc1',   'loc2', 'loc2',  'loc3',  'loc1'],
        "category": ['cat1', 'cat3', 'cat1',  'cat3',  'cat2'],
    })

groupdf= data.groupby(["location","category"]).aggregate("sum")
print(groupdf)

for g in groupdf.columns:
    trace = go.Bar(
               x=groupdf.index,
               y=groupdf[g],
               showlegend = True
    )
    layout = go.Layout(
                 title="test",
    )
    data=[trace]
    fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
    fig.show()
```

how to visualize  **groupdf** on **bar chart** using **plotly**?

Comment: What have you tried? Is the documentation unclear? https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/

Comment: try this:`fig = px.bar(df, x='location', y='source_number', color='category', barmode='group')`

Comment: this was not what i want i need to make the y axis as **category**

Comment: Is this the one you're looking for? `fig = px.bar(df, x='location', y='source_number', color='category')`